# How can I get TexShop to colour and typeset LaTeX source when filename has .m extension

Tags: texshop

I want to use TeXShop to color and typeset a file with the following sort of content, but the filename must have a .m extension (not .tex).  The reason is that it must be easy for others to use in Matlab/Octave.  Currently my TeXShop refuses to do either.  Any suggestions?

```
%{
%!TEX root = Doc.tex
\section{A 2D test of projective integration}
\label{sec:2tpi}
Try the nonlinear fast-slow system ...
\begin{matlab}
%}
fn=@(x,t) [-x(1)*x(2);-x(2)+x(1)^2]
ts=linspace(0,5,21);
xs=ode23(fn,[1;-1],ts)
plot(ts,xs)
%{
\end{matlab}
%}
```

Comment: Why not simply compile from the command line? ... Not that this file is a valid LaTeX file, however, so I don't see how you could ever compile what you've posted. And (I ask from ignorance) why doesn't `texshop` know to compile `Doc.tex`?

Comment: Because it is much more convenient to typeset from within the editor, here TeXShop.  But also TeXShop does not color the source file either.  (Although it does know keyboard shortcuts for the macros.)

Comment: Is 'Doc.tex' the masterfile and the problem is that files ending `.m` make it so that texshop does not recognize the the master `.tex` file?

Comment: 1. Yes, Doc.tex is the master file.  2. No, because if I remove "%!TEX root = Doc.tex" then still nothing happens upon requesting it be typeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to the list of file extensions that TeXShop recognizes by using the following hidden preference.  From the terminal type:

```
defaults write TeXShop OtherTeXExtensions -array-add "m"
```

This will add your type `.m` files to the list of files it recognizes. You may need to GetInfo on the file from the finder to change the default application to open that file type to TeXShop. (On my machine it defaults to TextWrangler.) Once you've done that, TeXShop should be able to open the file, and it will colour any included TeX syntax correctly.

Comment: As I expected,  one also needs to execute "ln -s filename.m filename.tex" in order for LaTeX "\include{filename}" to work in the Doc.tex.

Comment: @TonyRoberts You shouldn't be using `\include` for such files. If you use `\input{filename.m}` the file will be included without needing a link. (Unrelated: if this answer solved your problem, it's helpful also to "accept" it by clicking on the green tick mark below the voting arrows.)

Comment: Yet another downvote without a comment. Could the downvoter possibly explain?

Comment: Thanks for the advice about the tick---have now done so.   Regarding \include{} versus \input{}: thanks for the thought but I do know what I want to do here---I do want the option to control whether I typeset source files or not.  I am preparing for a project with a dozen or so principal functions, and each function with at least several test scripts: while working on one function and its tests I do not want to typeset other functions and their documentation.